# Facebook Login: App not setup: this app is still in development mode

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, facebook-authentication

When I try to use Facebook login during development I have this message appear in the web browser.

Comment: you need to be a lot more specific on stackoverflow. questions with just one sentence are way too broad in general. please add your research too - after all, there are a LOT of google results about the exact same error message already.

Answer (score 0):

First, I got added to the Facebook app. This could solve the problem but I was still seeing this message. What I came to find was that I had previously signed into a different Facebook on the simulator I was testing on. After going to Safari and logging into the account associated with the Facebook app everything worked as planned.

Comment: you do know that you are only allowed to have one facebook account, and with your real name, right? just saying.